# ADFS3.0 OAuth2.0 Refresh Token Flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, adfs3.0, refresh-token

I was able to get the Access Token and Refresh Token from an ADFS3.0 server. I was able to send the Refresh Token token to the Token endpoint (as explained in the question [Using ADFS OAuth Refresh Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079767/using-adfs-oauth-refresh-token)) to generate a new Access Token. However, I am not getting back a new refresh token. How do I force ADFS to send a new refresh token as well in the Refresh flow?